# Best free alternative to Acrobat SDK in order to manipulate PDF document in c# .net

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, bookmarks, acrobat-sdk

I need to add bookmarks to pdf documet without using Acrobat SDK (that needs the full Acrobat professional installed).
I'm using iTextSharp but is was made for Java and the porting to .net it is not complete.
Do you know an free alternative or documentation to do it?

Comment: Do you need a "free as in beer" solution?

Comment: my opinion is ItextSharp is the best free alternative to acrobat sdk

Comment: problem is: iTextSharp is free for open source projects only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're claim that "*iTextSharp but is was made for Java and the porting to .net it is not complete*" is quite **mistaken**. The main differences are [listed here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/71).

Adding bookmarks with iTextsharp is simple. See the API for [PdfOutline](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfOutline.html) and [PdfDestination](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfDestination.html). Here is a simple example to get you started:

```
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
    document, Response.OutputStream
  );
  document.Open();
  PdfOutline root = writer.RootOutline;
  string section = "Section {0}";
  string paragraph = "Paragraph {0}";
  for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {
    PdfOutline sectionBookmark = new PdfOutline(
      root, 
      new PdfDestination(
        PdfDestination.FITH, writer.GetVerticalPosition(true)
      ),
      string.Format(section, ++i)
    );
    document.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format(section, i)));
    for (int j = 0; j < 4;) {
      PdfOutline subSectionBookmark = new PdfOutline(
        sectionBookmark,
        new PdfDestination(
          PdfDestination.FITH, writer.GetVerticalPosition(true)
        ),
        string.Format(paragraph, ++j)
      );
      document.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format(paragraph, j)));
    }
    document.NewPage();
  }
}
```

Above example tested in a web environment with 5.1.3. If your devlopment environment is different, replace `Response.OutputStream` above with the [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) of your choice.

Comment: Thx! I'm going to accept yor answer, but beacuse I need to add bookmark to an existing document, and bookmark needs to have a javascript inside, my puropose is a little bit different from your code to. My question is, what's the equivalent of PDFstamper.setOutline method present in Java and not in c#?

Comment: It's a property in C# => `stamper.Outlines = outlines;`. Whenever you can't find something in C# look for a property with the `set` removed from the Java method name. And sorry, now that I read your comment, I should have realized you're using an existing PDF. Do you have [the book](http://itextpdf.com/book/)? Even if you don't, take a look at the [Chapter 7 examples](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx), maybe starting with [this one](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter07&ex=BookmarkedTimeTable). It should help.